# OpenVpn Routing Problems

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I just installed a new clean install of openVpn Server version 2.10.2 on an Ubuntu 20.x. So far so good,
my server has 1 physical interface with one public ip. When i use the default i can connect to it and
most works but here is the few issues I have and I am hoping someone can point me in right direction on
how to solve them.

***Some Prefix***

there a 2 Public c classes behind my remote firewall as well as 3 C classes witch are private but are not
nat'd but routed. The interface of my Access server is in one of the 2 public C's and ends with 11. I can
ping from the console of the Access Server all Subnets , private or public fine.

1. ) when i set my Should VPN clients have access to private subnets
   (non-public networks on the server side)? to Yes use Routing    and
   specify **192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.8.0/24** in the next
   textbox 1 per line and have selected Yes for all other 3.   i can
   access the Ip's on the public side and access the internet, i also
   see an entry for the default route in my clients route table  but i cant access the ip's on the private network

   ```
     0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.34    281
     0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0  192.168.240.129  192.168.240.132    257
   ```

2.) if i go and and set Should client Internet traffic be routed
through the VPN? to No i no longer have the default route and i see
private routes in my pc's route table  as well as the dns still goes to vpn

```
  8.8.4.4  255.255.255.255  192.168.240.161  192.168.240.163    102
  8.8.8.8  255.255.255.255  192.168.240.161  192.168.240.163    102
  192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0  192.168.240.161  192.168.240.163    102
  192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0  192.168.240.161  192.168.240.163    102
  192.168.8.0    255.255.255.0  192.168.240.161  192.168.240.163    102
```

in this case the DNS is no longer reachable as well as neither
of the hosts on the private routed Network.

So what my goal is to have my Client to use the Internet including DNS servers without the VPN as well as be able to reach
any of the public and private Subnets via the VPN. So not sure what i am missing here
Also based on some docs the config file was suposed to be in the ubuntu /etc dir but i cant find anything
Thanks

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.x release - please be specific.   (*20.04 was the end of the development cycle that started with 18.10 being the LTS, 20.10 the start of a different development cycle so 20.04 & 20.10 are different products, from differing cycles, or do you mean a Ubuntu Core 20 system - please clarify*)

Comment: Not sure that the Ubuntu version makes a huge difference in this case as i think the issue is with openVpn, but to make you happy its Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Your last comment highlights one issue, either you're not using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but a system that was based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  (Are you using Ubuntu), or you've not applied any system upgrades since 2020 which may also be your issue.  Refer [20.04.2 release[(https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/) which refers to ISO release, with installed systems upgraded weeks before that date, however a fully-upgraded 20.04 system has reported 20.04.4 for some time now.  I'd suggest checking what OS/release you're using; if it is Ubuntu - please apply upgrades.

Comment: Again this is not an unbuntu issue but a config issue of openvpn.

Comment: Then it looks like you need to find support for openVPN. You are ignoring the help you are getting here.

Comment: If you are refering to guiverc comments i would not consider them of any help of any kind. I did not th this in ubuntu but as openVpn issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more research i was able to confirm that the issue is not Ubuntu related. In my case actually the config was correct on the OpenVPN AS server but due to the fact that i used private ip's which are routed and not NAT it requires the private Subnet of the AS to be fully routable as in that mode the AS forwards all requests with private IP. So i hope that can help someone else and save some time.